# Prove the function $f(x)= \begin{cases}x^2 & x\in\mathbb{Q}\\-x^2 & else\end{cases}$ is differentiable at $x=0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

> Prove the function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)= \begin{cases}x^2 & x\in\mathbb{Q}\\-x^2 & else\end{cases}$
>
> is differentiable at $x=0$ and that $f'(0)=0$.

Hey everyone, this is a simple calculus problem I've encountered, but I don't really know how to prove this using the definition $lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=f'(x)$ because of the cases. It is trivial that if $x\in\mathbb{Q}$ then $f'(x)=2x$, else $f'(x)=-2x \Rightarrow$ both limits of these functions are zero when $x$ is approaching zero, but how do I formally prove the function is differentiable at $0$?
Thanks :)

Comment: $f$ is **not** differentiable at any $x\neq0$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \left| \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}\right|=\lim_{x \to 0} \left| \frac{f(x)}{x}\right|=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x^2}{|x|}=\lim_{x \to 0}|x|=0$$

Hence $$\lim_{x \to 0}  \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}=0$$

Answer (score 2):

$$ \frac {f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}= \begin{cases}  x & x\in\mathbb{Q}\\-x & else\end{cases}$$
Thus  $$ \frac {f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}\to 0\implies $$

$$ f'(0)=0$$

Answer (score 1):

Even more: $g$ differentiable at $0$, $g(0) = g'(0) = 0,|f|\le |g|\implies$ $f$ differentiable at $0$, $f'(0) = 0$. Proof: when $x\to 0$,
$$
\left|\frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x - 0}\right| =
\left|\frac{f(x)}{x}\right|\le
\left|\frac{g(x)}{x}\right| = 
\left|\frac{g(x) - g(0)}{x - 0}\right|\rightarrow|g'(0)| = 0. 
$$